# The value is in the table but selected value is NULL

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this PHP function. I receive an "In warningCheck function" message in my logcat window so there isn't an issue with calling the function. But when I check the $Latx and $Lonx values they are NULL, even though the data exists in the table.
(Timex is milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:01; locations is the table name; Latx and Lonx are columns in the table)

```
// warningCheck function
function warningCheck (){

    echo "In warningCheck function";        

    // get last input of user2 location from separate table
    $getCycData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM locationsa ORDER BY Timex DESC LIMIT 1");
    $cycDetails = mysql_fetch_row($getCycData);
    echo "cycDetails" . $cycDetails;
    $Latx = $cycDetails["Latx"];
    $Lonx = $cycDetails["Lonx"];

    echo "Values: " . $Latx . " " . $Lonx;
}
```

Comment: for this line $cycDetails = mysql_fetch_row($getCycData);, try to use $cycDetails = mysql_fetch_array($getCycData);

Comment: `mysql` is Depriciated.`$cycDetails = mysql_fetch_row($getCycData);` would give you a numeric Array. Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`. Does `echo "cycDetails" . $cycDetails;` not create an Array String conversion error?

Answer (score 0):

As php documentation on [mysql_fetch_row()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) says:

> mysql_fetch_row() fetches one row of data from the result associated with the specified result identifier. The row is returned as an array. Each result column is stored in an array offset, starting at offset 0.

So, either use mysql_fetch_assoc() if you want to access the fields by name, or use the column number to access the relevant data.

Pls note, that mysql_*() functions are deprecated and should not be used. Use mysqli or pdo instead.